# macOS Sierra 10.12 ghost window space

Tags: windows, macos, bug

After installing macOS Sierra 10.12, I have started seeing these ghost windows across the top of the screen. Unfortunately they are appearing at random and I can not determine if this is the OS, a specific application, or a general bug of some kind.

Has anyone else come across this and a way to fix it without rebooting your Mac?

**Example:**
[image]
**Updates**

- I have tried restarting finder...
- It seems to occur after the screen saver is initiated but I can not confirm...

**Plan of Attack**

- Next time is occurs I am planning on running through all of these [commands](http://www.thxbye.de/mac/mac-restarting-the-mac-os-x-dock-finder-spaces-or-menubar.html).

Comment: I experiencing these lay out rendering issues too, seems to be a 'no one tells me to rendering this place and I dont care.'. **Maybe** Sierra on rendering/repaint screen process, just make it where is responsible to do, otherwise will listen when need process that location, but if an app dont send this message, Sierra just dont update that location. Just curious, these windows matches with any screen size of one of your apps?

Comment: no, it actually looks like a space, but under the spaces across the top

Comment: that can makes sense. when happening again check which app is exactly at position of 'ghost window', close it, and try reproduce the 'ghost window'. My best guess is: one particular app doesnt call or implement a task, that in the new API is now required.

Comment: i have tried closing all apps, and that does nothing.  it's like a frozen space.

Comment: Now we have agents, try quit one by one, to see if the 'ghost' disapear.

Comment: which agents are you referring to?

Comment: Caffeine, Dropbox, Creative cloud manager... Apps on menu bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed that running `killall -KILL Dock` fixes this issue. 
http://www.thxbye.de/mac/mac-restarting-the-mac-os-x-dock-finder-spaces-or-menubar.html

Answer (score 0):

Force quit Finder.app using this method:

- Terminal: "killall Finder"

or

- hold the Option key and right click on the Finder icon in the dock. Select "Relaunch"

Comment: that did not work